# How to remove Ubuntu from dual boot in Kali?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kali-linux, dual-boot, shared-partition

My laptop has a 2Gb ram & 500Gb of rom & I've ubuntu installed but a few days back I dual booted & installed Kali linux by creating a 100 Gb partition using Ubuntu Live USB. Now I want to completely use Kali Linux & want to delete the Ubuntu partition without losing my files of Kali. So what should I do so that Ubuntu is deleted & the partition can be resized for Kali without harming the files in Kali.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Delete Partition on `Unix/Linux`**

Load your `Kali Linux`. After that write in terminal:

```
fdisk /dev/sdaWithYourUbuntuPartition
```

Enter `d` symbol. After entering, ask me to enter the partition number that I want to delete. Suppose I need to delete the 4th section, then I enter "4". Everything, the section has been deleted. Enter `w` to record all changes! New changes will only work after the next reboot of the system. This can be easily understood from the conclusion below.

How to resize your `sda` check here tutorial: https://www.ryadel.com/en/resize-extend-disk-partition-unallocated-disk-space-linux-centos-rhel-ubuntu-debian/